# How do I move that div with CSS in a clean way?

Tags: css, html

I am doing some CSS and I posted the result there:

http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/419882_389321854411184_131327856877253_1629934_584123648_n.jpg

I would like to move the little orange and grey div's up so that it's right below the blue one.

I know I can use position:absolute and move the div wherever I want, but this is obviously not the best way of doing it.

How would I have to do that?

Here is the CSS code for those 5 divs:

```
 #alldivs {
        width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; padding: 30px;
    }

    #green {
        width: 400px; height: 350px; margin: 0px; float: left; background: green;
    }

    #blue { width: 300px; height: 250px; margin: 0px; float: right; background: blue;
            }       

    #red { width: 400px; height: 200px; margin: 0px; float: left; background: red;
    }   

    #orange {
        width: 300px; height: 100px; float: right; background:orange;
    }

    #grey {
        width:300px; height:200px; float:right; background:grey;
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the css, wrap the blue and orange div; your html could be:

```
<div id="alldivs">
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="orange"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="grey"></div>
</div>
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/MHV4F/1/).

Comment: Hi scessor, Thanks a lot for your response. It's exactly what I was looking for. Regards

Answer (score 0):

On my phone so I can't test this...

Add float right to blue, grey, and orange.  And clear right the grey and orange.  Float left green and red. Have red clear left

**UPDATE**

Okay here ya go. This markup will allow you to be flexible with your css.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 700px;
        }

        .col_1 {
            float: left;
            width: 400px;   
        }

        .col_2 {
            float: right;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .green {
            height: 350px;
            background: green;  
        }

        .red {
            height: 200px;
            background: red;
        }

        .blue {
            height: 250px;
            background: blue;
        }

        .orange {
            height: 100px;
            background: orange;
        }

        .grey {
            height: 200px;
            background: grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="col_1">
            <div class="green"></div>
            <div class="red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col_2">
            <div class="blue"></div>
            <div class="orange"></div>
            <div class="grey"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi jjNford, thanks for your response. I tried your way but I still had the same problem. 
User scessor has suggested changing the html and it worked. 
I also found out that if div sizes of green=blue+orange, you only have to change order of div's in html. If the sizes don't coincide, then scessor's way works all the time

Comment: @eric01 good to hear, like I said, i was on my phone :P haha I just looked at  your link and what read what you were trying to do.  Didn't see look through your source, sorry, was planning on updating the answer today to help ya out, but looks like problem solved.